# How to display all hidden checkoboxes in a recyclerview on long press?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, view, android-view, onlongclicklistener

I made a layout for an item, with a hidden checkbox. On a long press, I want to make all checkboxes for all item in the recyclerview visible. I've tried to implement a long click listener but on a long press of an item only the check box for this specific item becomes visible.

Comment: Please provide your code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Adapter has 1 boolean to control visibility of checkbox in all items. If it is false, hide checkbox of the rows and vise versa
- When user long clicks on 1 item, change this boolean to true
- Right after that, call notifyDataSetChanged
- The list will display all checkboxes

Comment: can you provide a code example of this implementation?